# How to isolate functionalities between multiple jQuery Plugins in Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have more than 1 instance of the same plugin on the same page how can I separate functionality. eg. in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/3jwAK/, I have a plugin "`editor`" that appends a link simulating some plugin/widget button, that when clicked will append a line to the `textarea`.

The problem with it currently is it only targets the last `textarea`

Code looks like

**JS**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.editor = function(options) {
        var helpers = {
            rand: function() {
                return Math.round(Math.random() * 20);
            }   
        };

        return this.each(function() {
            $this = $(this);

            var div = $("<a>", {
                text: "Add Random Number",
                href: "#",
                click: function() {
                    $this.val( $this.val() + "\n" + helpers.rand() );
                }
            });

            $this.before(div);
        });

    }
})(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea name="txtArea1" cols="50" rows="6" id="editor1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the variable `$this` needs to be a local copy in each run of that function.  Put `var` in front of it.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Updated: http://jsfiddle.net/3jwAK/1/