# Multiple jQuery plugins in one file

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have multiple jquery plugins in one file under (function( $ )

If it is possible then I have a really wierd issue.  There are two plugins in my single file both sitting in the following structure:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

(function( $ ){
```

//PLUGINS HERE

```
})( jQuery );

});
```

Both are using the standard pattern of declaring the variable $this as a varablie within a .each iteration returning the main function of each plugin.

However, what is happening is that the plugin declared last is taking the $this variable from the the first pugin, even although the $this variable is declared within the .each function.  I thought javascript had function scop level so this should be possible.

EDIT:

Solved this.  This was the issue incase anyone else has the same issue in future:

[How to isolate functionalities between multiple jQuery Plugins in Same Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664971/how-to-isolate-functionalities-between-multiple-jquery-plugins-in-same-page)

Comment: Of course... Javascript is file-independent.

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript?! huh?! what?  Your `each` call creates its own scope, `var $this` will keep them from becoming global and overwriting each other.  If you don't `var`, it goes up the scope chain until it finds another `var`, if none found, it becomes completely global.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can declare as many extensions as you want. For want purpose, if you don't mind me asking?